# Trying to get songlist, but getting error

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a build a music player but there is a problem getting songlist from the SD card.
it's showing this error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0              
java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
```

Here's the `SongManager` code and this class should  return songlist

```
public class SongsManager {
    // SDCard Path
    final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/sound_recorder");

    //final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sound_recorder";
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager(){

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){

        Log.d("testsd", MEDIA_PATH);
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        //  if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) //don't use this to avoid null pointer exception !
        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())!=null) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();


                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList


                songsList.add(song);

            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
     * */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3") || name.endsWith(".3gpp") || name.endsWith(".wav")); //add more extensions here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you google IndexOutOfBoundsException to make an effort to understand what it is and why it's happening? Given this information, you should be able to debug/step through your code and find out what the issue is by inspecting whatever is throwing this error at runtime. Obviously `file.getName()` is returning a zero length string.

Comment: Always post the **full** stacktrace of your exception.

Answer (score -1):

Your array access code is trying to reach an element which doesnt exist in the range specified for the array list , debugging the last element being accessed from the array will help you in this regard

Comment: what are you trying to say in the last line after debugging word.

Comment: put a debugger at the line where the array is being accessed , ie file.getName.

Check if the loop condition is making the statement execute -sizeOfArray+1 times .